# Positioning on an image

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm having major issues settling some elements upon an image. I'm building a front-end site to move onto wordpress eventually. It has four pages all of which have an image at the top under the header. The finished version needs to look like this - 
[image: PSD Version]

This is where I'm at (the image is purposely different) - 
[image: Coded version]

This is one of the pages but all of them have the same issue with the 'see more / showreel' elements at the foot of the page which I think is also hindering the anchor link in the right hand corner.

Here's the relevant code I've been using, I think part of the issue is that I'm confusing the usage of id's and classes to identify elements on different pages.

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
/* GENERAL */

body {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

div.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}


/* AGENCY PAGE */

section#agency {
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: url(../images/VIDEO.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 960px;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

#agency a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 50px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.text {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}

.text p {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.text h1,
h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.text h2 {
  line-height: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.text h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.showreel {
  height: 50px;
  width: 960px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.showreel,
.showreel>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.showreel p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.showreel i {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.seemore i {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.seeour i {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section id="agency">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>VIDEO & ANIMATION</h2>
      <h1>FOR AGENCY</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel ex nisl. Vestibulum vitae ultricies nisl. Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque
        facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor. Suspendisse nec venenatis nisi. Phasellus sodales viverra ante quis efficitur. Pellentesque quis orci mi. Phasellus tempus, sapien ut luctus pellentesque, lacus risus accumsan lorem, in porta urna tellus
        ac nibh. Nunc varius elit non diam vehicula aliquet. In eget urna id orci molestie pulvinar. Integer quis risus eu erat iaculis aliquet ut at eros. Etiam feugiat, ante vel molestie finibus, lacus urna pharetra leo, ut lobortis massa lectus quis
        lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus turpis sagittis sapien vulputate sagittis. Nunc ac velit sollicitudin, consequat arcu ac, tincidunt risus.</p>
    </div>
    <a href="business.html">
      <p>I'm a business</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="container showreel">
    <div class="seemore">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#fff"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                     </span>
      <p>SEE MORE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="seeour">
      <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

(*The above html is specifically for the agency page below, the other pages use the same classes but a different id for the section*)

UPDATE -

Here's the css from further down the page -

```
section#products {
    height: 700px;
    max-width: 100%

}



.agencyproducts {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

}

.agencyproducts p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px;
}

.agencyproducts img {

    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1;
    top: 50%;

}

figure {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;

}

figure img {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.four {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.images img {

    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 10px;

}

.seemore {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 45%;
}

section#facebook {
    height: 250px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

.socialmedia {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    top: 125px;

}

.socialmedia i {

    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    top: 50%;
    color: #000000;

}

.socialmedia p {

    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;

}

section#form {
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
}


section#form h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

span {
    color: #d3d3d3;
}
.phone img, .phone p, .email img, .email p {
  float: left;
}
.email {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.phone p, .email p {
  margin: 3px 0 0 10px;
}
.phone::after, .email::after { /*clearfix*/
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

form {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

section#form div.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

section#form div.row input {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
section#form div.row input:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email] {
  background: #E8E8E8;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: #1ba4dd;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;

}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background: #00bfff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the problems you were having were do to the structure of your page, in addition to some base styles conflicting with your own. I'd suggest using a[css reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) file to prevent that from happening, otherwise you have to manually set certain properties to '0'.

Some of your css structure was confusing as well. You don't actually need to declare a div ID within the encompassing div ID to get it to work. That style of syntax is more reserved for specific elements of a div that need to be styled just within that context. Like an 'a' or 'img' tag.

Here's the codepen for my solution https://codepen.io/morganfens/pen/RgQGaw

HTML

```
<section id="agency">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="business.html">
      I'm a business
    </a>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>VIDEO & ANIMATION</h2>
      <h1>FOR AGENCY</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel ex nisl. Vestibulum vitae ultricies nisl. Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque
        facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor. Suspendisse nec venenatis nisi. Phasellus sodales viverra ante quis efficitur. Pellentesque quis orci mi. Phasellus tempus, sapien ut luctus pellentesque, lacus risus accumsan lorem, in porta urna tellus
        ac nibh. Nunc varius elit non diam vehicula aliquet. In eget urna id orci molestie pulvinar. Integer quis risus eu erat iaculis aliquet ut at eros. Etiam feugiat, ante vel molestie finibus, lacus urna pharetra leo, ut lobortis massa lectus quis
        lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus turpis sagittis sapien vulputate sagittis. Nunc ac velit sollicitudin, consequat arcu ac, tincidunt risus.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="container showreel">
    <div class="seemore">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#fff"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                    </span>
      <p>SEE MORE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="seeour">
      <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}

/* AGENCY PAGE */

#agency {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.thephoblographer.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Chris-Gampat-the-Phoblographer-X3-ND-filter-six-stop-review-sample-photos-5-of-8ISO-4001-2500-sec-at-f-2.0-680x453.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

#agency a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
/*   position: static; */
  float: right;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding:5px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}

.text p {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.text h1, h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.text h2 {
  line-height: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.text h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.showreel {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.showreel, .showreel > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.showreel p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.showreel i {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.seemore i {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.seeour i {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a reset file - are there different versions?

Comment: There are different versions. I usually use normalize.css, another possible  issue might be that the reset.css isn't linked in correctly.

Comment: I've noticed that my reset css file isn't quite the same as the one on your link so perhaps that's an issue I need to look at. Just so I can check I've done it right, how would you link to one?

Comment: I've used an old one from a couple of years ago and I think it had been modified for training purposes. It has these extra rules after the rules from the main site - img {
 vertical-align: bottom;
 max-width: 100%;
}

input, textarea, select {
 font: inherit;
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: The short answer is that they should be linked the same way as any other CSS file, they should be placed above any other CSS links in the header  to set them at a lower priority. The only difference that might come up for this is whether it's an external CSS link, which looks like this:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://linktosheet">

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is more css in your theme that is conflicting. Check this fiddle where i tried to position things https://jsfiddle.net/5t8nnu6r/

```
 /* GENERAL */

  body {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }

  div.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  }
  /* AGENCY PAGE */

  section#agency {
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/122400/pexels-photo-122400.jpeg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 960px;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
  }

  #agency a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
  }

  .text {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    left: 100px;
  }

  .text p {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  .text h1,
  h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }

  .text h2 {
    line-height: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 200;
  }

  .text h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }

  .showreel {
    height: 50px;
    width: 960px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 30px;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .showreel,
  .showreel > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .showreel p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .showreel i {
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .seemore i {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }

  .seeour i {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }

  #agency a.float-link {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }

  .showreel {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #agency a.float-link p {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
    margin-top: 96px;
  }

  .text h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .text p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
```

and

```
<section id="agency">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>VIDEO &amp; ANIMATION</h2>
      <h1>FOR AGENCY</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel ex nisl. Vestibulum vitae ultricies nisl. Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque
        facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor. Suspendisse nec venenatis nisi. Phasellus sodales viverra ante quis efficitur. Pellentesque quis orci mi. Phasellus tempus, sapien ut luctus pellentesque, lacus risus accumsan lorem, in porta urna tellus
        .

      </p>
    </div>
    <a href="business.html" class="float-link">
      <p>I'm a business</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="container showreel">
    <div class="seemore">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#fff"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                    </span>
      <p>SEE MORE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="seeour">
      <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Should I paste in my full css file?

Comment: I believe this should be left as a comment with the fiddle link

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead you only need to paste your css for that footer section since that's the issue we are trying to solve

Comment: @Huangism Other CSS added.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue

```
.seemore {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 45%;
}
```

remove both margins, not sure what this is for

```
.seemore {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

If the second `.seemore` is for another element somewhere then you need to target that more specifically, by adding a parent selector will do the trick in this case

Comment: Should I just change the class name?

Comment: You can do that too but it's really not hard to add a parent selector to it. I am not sure how the rest of your page is structured html wise, so it's hard to say what the best thing to do is. So if you want to change the name then sure. If you want the font size to be declared for the showreel part then just do `.showreel .seemore { font-size: 12px; }` I guess you can also add `margin: 0` to that and issue would be solved as well. Many ways to achieve this